# How to get a github branch to accept changes pushed from other branches but it keeps saying that there is nothing to commit?

Tags: git, github

Here's the story.

We have two branches.  Development, and then Master.  On Github, it's setup so we can only push from local to development on github and then we can only merge to master from github, and then we push to heroku from master.

We merged two branches to development, and then to master, and then pushed to Heroku.  One of the branches had a huge error we didn't catch in development.

So we reverted heroku back to what we had before (no problem).  But trouble arose when we started trying to roll back and revert the other branches.

Now, it's a mess.  And we tried a lot of things to fix it, all with no success.

Fast forward to right now: we got the development branch back of the code that worked, and tried to remerge that to master.  However, github said there were no differences, and thus no way to commit the changes.  However, when we look at the code on github for each branch, development had the code, and master did not.  So why is github telling us there are no differences?

Next, we reverted that development branch and tried to delete that development branch too.  We then tried to create the pull request again from scratch on development, and pushed it to github.  However, now it is telling us that again, there are no changes, so we can't merge to development.

We don't know what to do.  We can't seem to use the old branches.  We can't seem to recode the branches from scratch.  It seems github thinks some code that is there is not there, and other code that is not there, Github thinks is there.  Any ideas how we can resolve this?

Comment: We need to see *exactly* what you have done, rather than a description of what you have done. Worth noting: GitHub's display of a repository does not show enough. You will want to use local tools on your local repository (e.g., `git log --graph` or a graphical viewer).

Answer (score 0):

Its totally messed up. What I can infer from your post is that you want to revert back to the code.

Do       `git log -v`

I will show you all the commits. Now find the commit id number where you want to get back to or revert the changes to.

Then do `git reset --hard <commit-id>`
But mind that you wouldn't be able to get revert the reset. So better create a branch using git

```
git branch <branch-name>
git checkout <branch-name>
```

You will get back to that commit.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It seems we were able to get development to have the right code, but now, when we try to merge dev to master, it still says that there is no difference between the branches.  But 'master' definitely is not showing any of the code that github apparently says that it has.

Comment: No, don't use `git reset` here. @MonroeMann: the reset will cause the branch to be far behind, so that there is nothing to merge.

Answer (score 0):

We learned a bit about git rebase and appear to have solved the issue.  We finally got everything working again.  Here is how we fixed it, and I can explain our new workflow as well to ensure it doesn't happen again:

a) Never merge two or more branches live to production at the same time.  Push each one separately, test live, and if everything still works, then push the next approved branch live to production.  This way, if there's a problem, you don't have to rollback the good code with the bad.  You can just roll back that one PR that caused the errors, and continue pushing the good code.

b) Learn about git rebase.  While we are not experts, learning the basics did help us solve some of the issues.

c) We discovered how to use git force to make git do what you want when it's being temperamental.

d) We learned that just because you think you have tested everything to perfection and there's no way a PR pushed live to production could cause an issue... it can.  And very well might.

So while our new workflow is slower, and we are more careful, the result is that we can easily rollback deploys that crash the site, because now, it's just one PR that we KNOW is causing the crash.  And then the site is back up and running, and we can just work on figuring out what to do to fix the bug.